# Скопировать файл и поменять его конечное имя в соответствии с версией

Tags: cmd, powershell

Не спрашивайте почему, меня это тоже очень волнует. Но так хочет заказчик.

Необходимо скопировать файл `X:\Folder1\Folder2\...\Project.exe` в папку `\\Server\Folder3\Folder4\...\` и переименовать его как `Project_1.5.6047.21408.exe`, где `1.5.6047.21408` номер версии файла.

Comment: `Project.exe` - это .net приложение?

Comment: Да, приложение. Оно имеет версию файла. (Свойства -> Подробно -> Версия файла(Версия продукта))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В Powershell доступны любые функции .NET Framework, поэтому версию файла можно получить через метод [FileVersionInfo.GetVersionInfo](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.fileversioninfo(v=vs.110).aspx).

```
# файл для копирования и переименования
$input = 'X:\Folder1\Folder2\...\Project.exe'

# каталог назначения
$output = '\\Server\Folder3\Folder4\...\'

$path = [System.IO.Path]

$version = [System.Diagnostics.FileVersionInfo]::GetVersionInfo($input).ProductVersion.ToString()
$newFile = $path::GetFileNameWithoutExtension($input) + "_$version" + $path::GetExtension($input)
$output = $path::Combine($output, $newFile)

Copy-Item "$input" -Destination "$output"
```

Вместо `ProductVersion` можно попробовать `FileVersion`.

Comment: По сути мне нужна была только `[System.Diagnostics.FileVersionInfo]::GetVersionInfo($input).ProductVersion.ToString()` спасибо!